# Why `0 instanceof Number` is false?

Tags: javascript

I know following expression is `true`:

```
[1, 2] instanceof Array
```

And that's a correct approach to distinct an Array from Object. But why following expression is `false`?

```
0 instanceof Number
```

Comment: Because `0` is a primitive.

Comment: Because of primitive types, try `new Number(5) instanceof Number`